Definition of derivative of exponential map in Do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry"
In the proof of Gauss' Lemma, Do carmo uses the notation $(d exp_p)_v v$ in Gauss' Lemma, but he doesn't seem to define it anywhere. If anyone could shed some insight, would be appreciated :)


The exponential map at $p$ is a map $\exp_p:\Omega_p\to M$ where $\Omega_p$ is some open subset of $T_pM$. Notice that $T_pM$ is a vector space, hence a smooth manifold, and $\Omega_p$ is an open subset, so it’s a smooth manifold in its own right. Next, $M$ is obviously a smooth manifold, and we have that $\exp_p$ is a map from the manifold $\Omega_p$ into the manifold $M$, and it is easy to prove smoothness.
So, for any ‘point’ $v\in \Omega_p$ we can consider the tangent map/differential/pushforward (there are a bunch of names…) which is a linear map $d(\exp_p)_v:T_v(\Omega_p)\to T_{\exp_p(v)}M$. So, for any tangent vector $\xi\in T_v(\Omega_p)$, we can consider the tangent vector $d(\exp_p)_v(\xi)\in T_{\exp_p(v)}M$.
Hopefully this all makes sense; I’m just carrying out the general definitions for $f:N\to M$ and $df_p:T_pN\to T_{f(p)}M$ for a point $p\in N$, and surely Do Carmo covers these definitions.

What’s special in this case is that $T_pM$ is a vector space, so $\Omega_p$ is an open set in a vector space, so for each ‘point’ $v\in \Omega_p$ there is a canonical isomorphism $T_v(\Omega_p)\cong T_pM$ (in general if $V$ is a vector space and $\Omega\subset V$ is open, then for each $v\in\Omega$, $T_v\Omega\cong V$). As a result (after composing by a suitable isomorphism on the domain) you can think of the differential of the exponential map as a linear map $d(\exp_p)_v:T_pM\to T_{\exp_p(v)}M$. So, for any vector $w\in T_pM$, I can produce the vector $d(\exp_p)_v(w)\in T_{\exp_p(v)}M$.
Finally, notice that in this special case, we have $v\in \Omega_p\subset T_pM$, so we can consider $d(\exp_p)_v(v)\in T_{\exp_p(v)}M$. Notice that the two $v$’s play different roles. The $v$ in the subscript is the point at which we’re taking the derivative, and the $(v)$ in parentheses refers to the tangent vector, and the linear map is being applied on this vector.
